# java gwt don't show cursor

Tags: java, gwt, cursor

I have added a clickhandler to a label which works fine. But when I mouseover the label a cursor instead of the mousearrow is shown (the clickhandler still works fine). Is it possible to set something so the mousearrow remains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a label like

```
<g:Label addStyleNames="{style.mytext}">MyText</g:Label>
```

Just add the following to its style

```
.mytext {
   cursor: default;
}
```

Or `cursor: pointer`, `cursor: help`, ...

**Alternative**

Or turn the `<g:Label>` into a `<g:Anchor href="..." addStyleNames="{style.myanchor}">`. To avoid the default underline, you may want to add a style

```
.myanchor {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```